# Change Top Links Text after Login

Tags: toplinks

I want to change the text of My account top links.

When user is not logged in, I need to display the top link **My Account** as **Register**.

Once a user is logged in, I want to change that text to from **Register** to '**Your account**'.

How can I achieve this ?

Please Help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned before you can edit your local.xml file.
It should be in your theme folder e.g.:
app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourversion/layout/local.xml
If it´s not there you can create it. It`s a very good way to edit the layout xml for a theme.

**Remove "My Account" for the default handle**

```
<default>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="removeLinkByUrl">
            <url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/>
        </action>
    </reference>
 </default>
```

**Add "Register" for the logged out handle**

```
<customer_logged_out>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
            <label>Register</label>
            <url helper="customer/getLogInUrl"/>
            <prepare/>
            <urlParams/>
        </action>
    </reference>
</customer_logged_out>
```

**Add "My Account" for the logged in handle**

```
<customer_logged_in>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
            <label>Your Account</label>
            <url helper="customer/getAccountUrl" />
            <prepare/>
            <urlParams/>
            <liParams>
                <id>header-account-link</id>
            </liParams>
            <aParams/>
            <beforeText/>
            <afterText/>                 
        </action>
    </reference>
</customer_logged_in>
```

In app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/customer.xml you can find the possible handles and url helper etc.